# Combining SOQL Queries

Tags: soql, aggregate, aggregateresult, inner-join, outer-join

I need to pull out a query that fetches:

From My Team object and Package object. Package is a child of Teams

From teams I need to pull how many packages is currently in teams and how much each packages weigh in total:

```
SELECT SUM(Weight__c) TotalWeight, COUNT(id) numOfPackages, 
Team__r.Phone, Team__r.Name,Team__r.id FROM Package__c GROUP BY 
Team__r.Phone, Team__r.Name,Team__r.Id
```

But I also need to know the last package that was added to the team:

```
SELECT Id,  (SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, weight__c FROM Package__r 
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Team__c
```

How, if possible, could I combine these two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a Master-Detail relationship between Teams and Packages?  If so you can utilize a Roll-up field to both sum the weight of all packages, as well as show a count of all packages.  These fields would exist on the Teams object.

If you are not using a Master-Detail relationship you might consider using the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) tool to accomplish the same thing.

Then you could use the query you already have to get the most recent package, with the two new roll-up fields in the parent part.

`SELECT Id, Total_Packages__c, Packages_Sum_Weight__c, (SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, weight__c FROM Package__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Team__c`

Comment: Unfortunately I am not.

Comment: @kh9876 In that case I think your best option is to use your second query remove the limit clause, and loop through all records to calculate the total weight.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this in SOQL (or for that matter any query language).

The requirement need two types of information:
1) Sum of Weight__c along with other details
2) Most resent package

Both above result need different sets of data so this can not be combine into one query.